# How to Sort Numeric Array in JMeter Beanshell

Tags: java, jmeter, beanshell

I am new to using Beanshell/Java in my JMeter scripts. I have following code in my JMeter Beanshell Processor.

```
int count = Integer.parseInt(vars.get("student_id_RegEx_matchNr"));
String delimiter = ",";
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
for(int i=1;i<=25;i++) { 
sb.append(vars.get("student_id_RegEx_" + i));
if (i == count){
break; //to eliminate comma after the array
}else {
sb.append(delimiter);
}
}
vars.putObject("myUnsortedVar",sb.toString());
```

I get following as output when I run script:

```
myUnsortedVar=5,6,2,3,1,4
```

I want it to be sorted numerically like this and also stored in a new variable named "sortedVar".

```
1,2,3,4,5,6
```

What code can I use to sort this and also store in a new variable so I can use the sorted array in coming JMeter requests. Thanks for help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As OndreJM suggested, you need to change your approach. Instead of storing values in StringBuffer, store them in ArrayList and then use `Collections.sort` to sort it. Following code should work for you.

```
// create an ArrayList
ArrayList strList = new ArrayList();
for (int i=0;i<25; i++){
strList.add(vars.get("student_id_RegEx_" + String.valueOf(i+1)));
}
// sort this ArrayList
Collections.sort(strList);
// use StringBuilder to build String from ArrayList
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
for (String id: strList){
builder.append(id);
builder.append(",");
}
builder.deleteCharAt(builder.length()-1);
// finally put in variable using JMeter built in 'vars.put'
// do not use vars.putObject, as you can not send object as request parameter
vars.put("sortedVar", builder.toString());
```

Answer (score 1):

Taking `sb.toString() = "5,6,2,3,1,4"`.

- Use `String::split()` to convert from `String` to `String[]`.
- Use [`Arrays::sort()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) to sort the array
- Use `Arrays.toString()` to convert from `String[]` to `String`

```
String[] sortedArray = Arrays.sort(sb.toString().split(","));
vars.putObject("mySortedVar", Arrays.toString(sortedArray));
```

Comment: I removed following.. vars.putObject("myUnsortedVar",sb.toString());
and added
String[] sortedArray = Arrays.sort(sb.toString().split(","));
vars.putObject("mySortedVar", Arrays.toString(sortedArray));
Not working. throwing error.

Comment: 2015/09/03 08:27:57 ERROR - jmeter.util.BeanShellInterpreter: Error invoking bsh method: eval Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``int count = Integer.parseInt(vars.get("student_id_RegEx_matchNr")); String delim . . . '' : Typed variable declaration : Void initializer. 
2015/09/03 08:27:57 WARN  - jmeter.protocol.java.sampler.BeanShellSampler: org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterException: Error invoking bsh method: eval Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``int count = Integer.parseInt(vars.get("student_id_RegEx_matchNr")); String delim . . . '' : Typed variable declaration : Void initializer.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that in bean shell you may use the same as in Java. Once you fill StringBuffer, there is not easy way to sort the contents. Therefore I would store the contents first into an intermediate `ArrayList<String>` (or even better `ArrayList<Integer>` if you always get numbers), then sort it using `Collections.sort`, and then use another `for` cycle to put the list's contents into StringBuffer using the comma delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
char [] responseCharArray = vars.get("myUnsortedVar").toCharArray();
Arrays.sort(responseCharArray);
String mySortedString = Arrays.toString(responseCharArray);    
vars.put("mySortedVar", mySortedString.replaceAll("\\,\\,","").replaceAll(" ",""));
```

See [How to use BeanShell: JMeter's favorite built-in component](https://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) guide for more information on Beanshell scripting in JMeter

Comment: Initially, this code gave me error when executed. Then I removed the 'replaceAll()' from last line and it gave me this output in variable that is not valid in my case:
[,, ,, ,, ,, ,, ,, ,, ,, ,, ,, ,, ,, ,, ,, ,, ,, ,, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8, 9, 9]

Comment: It is very clever of you to remove the line which normalizes the output

Comment: Dmitri, as I mentioned that JMeter returns me error when I use that line. When I remove it, It gives me above result. I shared this info so you can look if something needs to be fixed in last line. I am a beginner in Java, so please forgive for asking basics. Thanks.

Comment: error I get is this ... 
ERROR - jmeter.util.BeanShellInterpreter: Error invoking bsh method: eval Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``int count = Integer.parseInt(vars.get("student_id_RegEx_matchNr")); String delim . . . '' Token Parsing Error: Lexical error at line 16, column 53.  Encountered: "," (44), after : "\"\\"

Comment: looks like a copy-paste issue to me, there is no `"\"\\,"` in my code

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. I made the correction and it executed perfectly; but the output is still not as expected.

myUnsortedVar=13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,4,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,
mySortedVar=[0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5,6,6,6,7,7,7,8,8,8,9,9,9]

Comment: You need exclude duplicates? You need `0,1,2,3,4...`?